# UIButton selector error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am adding four to five views to the UIScrollview.

i am creating that views dynamically at run time.

all that views contain one button.

```
{

    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(category_selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

views are successfully added, but when i am clicking button "*unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x657e850*" is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `category_selected:` method in your controller. The signature should look like this:

```
- (void)category_selected:(UIButton*)sender
{
    // The sender is the button that was pressed.
}
```

When you set up the button like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(category_selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I am assuming that you are calling this from your controller, so `self` is the controller, and that is the class that must have the `category_selected:` implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined the method category_selected: in your class.

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(category_selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

category_selected:   method should be defined in the class in which you are setting the above action.

Answer (score 0):

I am having Category_Selected method. and i am calling category_selected.

That is i am having method whose first letter starts with Upper Case Letter, but i am calling method with first letter Lower Case.